# Xamarin Debugging - Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

We have a Xamarin app and have been debugging using Visual Studio 2019 against a physical device with no issues. We're trying to upgrade to Visual Studio 2022 but cannot debug against the device. The debugger crashes with this error. Has anyone had this problem? I'm at a loss how to proceed.

**Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall**. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 585
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 592
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.b__0() in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1021
[E:RunShellCommand]:      R52T40K8JGK logcat -v time "dalvikvm:S" "ActivityThread:S" "mkestner:S" "MonoDroid-Debugger:S" failed: Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 585
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbClient.ReadLineWhile(Action`1 output, Func`1 predicate) in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Adb\AdbClient.cs:line 592
at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.b__0() in D:\a_work\1\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 1021

Tried restarting the ADBServer and the usual last resort tricks of clearing bin and obj folders but no joy.

Comment: The issue may be related to `Visual Studio 2022`, it's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thank you, I'll do that and see if they can help.

Comment: My pleasure, I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: @CraigKnight I experience the same problem, could you, please, attach a ticket if you reported about the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue in my case by enabling the 'Use Fast Deployment' option under project properties -> Android Options.

Note in my situation I had been using Visual Studio 2022 for a while now but had not had this issue before when using my usual physical Android 13 test device. I only ran into this issue when I switched to a Android 9 test device.